# What does " if(true) " means?

Tags: php, oop

I'm building a functionality which displays a message dynamically, i.e if the forms are correctly filled or not.
I came across this piece of code and I don't understand how does it really work.

```
if(true) {
$this->flash('Yay ! File uploaded successfully', 'success');
} else {
$this->flash('There is some error', 'error');
```

From what I've already looked for, I guess it's used to see whether or not there is an array available, since PHP returns false if there isn't one.
(according to PHP manual )
I still don't get how does this work, there is no variables such as if($foo) but just plain boolean on this condition.

And yes, it seems to work as intended.

Thanks for your enlightments.

Comment: Looks like a bug as you wouldn't need to do the check or have an else clause in this case. But it is commonly used in while loops and switch statements.

Comment: Sorry my bad I missed a HUGE thing.
It was just a placeholder, or debugging thing or whatever you can call it to easily test the "else" condition. ( replacing true to false ).
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a debugging statement left in.

```
if(true)
```

This is always true, so you could remove the test entirely and just run with the true statement.